# How to check an input is not blank and is a number greater than zero in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying write a program in python to calculate heart rate training zones (using Karvonen's formula for anyone who is interested :-) ).

The formula is different for men and women but both require age (alder), resting heart rate (hvilepuls) and max heart rate (makspuls).

The code calculates max heart rate if the individual just presses enter.

I wanted to catch blank inputs for age and resting heart, and also values inputted for all three variables that are zero or less.

I have been able to catch blank inputs but I cannot seem to combine it with the zero or less ones as well.

The code I have written is below and works but does not stop people enter numbers that are equal to or less than zero.

Any other general comments about cleaning-up the code and better (more pythonic perhaps?) ways of writing this are much appreciated.

```
# Karvonens formel
#
print(
"""
Kalkulere dine treningssoner for lett løping, anaerob terskel (AT) og VO2 Max treningsøkter.

Instruksjoner

1. Fyll inn din alder, hvilepuls og kjønn.
2. Skriv inn din maksimale hjertefrekvens, hvis du vet det, ellers trykk enter - deretter beregnet programmet det selv som følger:
(Menn 214 - (0,8 * alder) Kvinner:. 209 - (0,7 * alder).

3. Treningssonenes verdier beregnes ved hjelp av Karvonen formelen:
X% = (Maksimal hjertefrekvens hvilepuls) * x/100) + hvilepuls
"""
)

kjonn=""
alder=""
hvilepuls=""
makpuls=""


while kjonn.lower() != "m" and kjonn.lower() != "d":
    kjonn = input("Hvilken kjønn er du? (M)ann/(D)ame\t")

while alder=="":
    alder = int(input("Hvor mange år er du?\t"))

while hvilepuls=="":
    hvilepuls = int(input("Hva er din hvilepuls?\t"))

makspuls = input("Hva er din makspuls?\t")


if makspuls=="":
    if kjonn.lower()=="m":
        makspuls = int(214 - 0.8*int(alder))
    elif kjonn.lower() =="d":
        makspuls = int(209 - 0.7*int(alder))
    else:
        print("\n\nEnter M or D")
else:
    makspuls=int(makspuls)

prosent60 = (makspuls-hvilepuls)*0.6 + hvilepuls
prosent75 = (makspuls-hvilepuls)*0.75 + hvilepuls
prosent85 = (makspuls-hvilepuls)*0.85 + hvilepuls
prosent90 = (makspuls-hvilepuls)*0.9 + hvilepuls

# Remove decimals
prosent60 = int(prosent60)
prosent75 = int(prosent75)
prosent85 = int(prosent85)
prosent90 = int(prosent90)


print("\n\n")
if kjonn.lower()=="m":
    print("Din kjønn  er:\t\tMann")
else:
    print("Din kjønn  er:\t\tDame")
print("Din alder er:\t\t", alder)
print("Din hvilepuls er:\t", hvilepuls," slag/min")
print("Din makspuls er:\t", makspuls," slag/min")

print("\n\n")
print("Din lavsone er:\t",prosent60,"-",prosent75," slag/min")
print("Din ATsone er:\t",prosent85,"-",prosent90," slag/min")
print("Din VO2max er:\t",prosent90,"-",makspuls," slag/min")


input("\n\nTrykk enter for å avslutte")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I suggest.

- Input should be validated, and cleaned up, immediately.  Usually when you take input, it is a good idea to call the `.strip()` method, in case the user entered extra spaces or tabs by mistake.  Right after you read the `'m'` or `'d'` value, force it to lower-case; then the rest of the code can assume it is lower-case.
- When you want to check one value against multiple possible legal values, a good Python idiom is to use `in (value0, value1, value2, ..., valueN)`.  In this case you could check `in ('m', 'd')`, but because we are checking for a single character, we can actually just check `in "md"` and that works too.
- When you want to allow an empty string or an integer, just read the response into a temp variable (I used the name `s` for "string temporary variable") and then you can check for a zero-length string; if it is not zero-length, convert to an integer.  You could initialize your integer variable to a negative value, and then loop until it is not negative; but I prefer to use the `while True:` loop and add an explicit `break` to show the success condition that breaks out.  (Note: if this is homework, your teacher may not agree with me; some teachers don't like to see `break` inside a loop, but rather prefer testing the loop only at the top.)
- I added some error messages.  I put "@@@@@" around my text to help make sure you find it all and localize it to your language.  (It's a short program so likely you could have found them all anyway, but I wanted to make it as easy as possible for you.)
- Instead of calling `int()` on floating-point numbers to convert them to integer, I used `round()`, so that 77.9 will become 78 rather than 77.

EDIT: I just edited the code.  I broke out the input validation into a function, with a "validator" function you pass in.  I think it is cleaner this way.

Code:

```
# Karvonens formel
#
print(
"""
Kalkulere dine treningssoner for lett lping, anaerob terskel (AT) og VO2 Max treningskter.

Instruksjoner

1. Fyll inn din alder, hvilepuls og kjnn.
2. Skriv inn din maksimale hjertefrekvens, hvis du vet det, ellers trykk enter - deretter beregnet programmet det selv som flger:
(Menn 214 - (0,8 * alder) Kvinner:. 209 - (0,7 * alder).

3. Treningssonenes verdier beregnes ved hjelp av Karvonen formelen:
X% = (Maksimal hjertefrekvens hvilepuls) * x/100) + hvilepuls
"""
)

kjonn=' '
alder=0
hvilepuls=0
makpuls=' '

def check_positive(n):
    if n > 0:
        return True
    else:
        print("@@@@@ Cannot enter a negative or 0 value! @@@@@")
        return False
def check_positive_or_zero(n):
    if n >= 0:
        return True
    else:
        print("@@@@@ Cannot enter a negative value! @@@@@")
        return False

def get_input_int(s_mesg, fn_validate, default=None):
    while True:
        s = input(s_mesg).strip()
        if not s and default is not None:
            return default
        # not a default value; try it as an int
        try:
            n = int(s)
        except ValueError:
            print("@@@@@ Not even an integer! @@@@@")
            continue
        # works as an int; is it valid?
        if fn_validate(n):
            return n


while kjonn not in ('m', 'd'):
    kjonn = input("Hvilken kjnn er du? (M)ann/(D)ame\t").strip().lower()

alder = get_input_int("Hvor mange r er du?\t", check_positive)
hvilepuls = get_input_int("Hva er din hvilepuls?\t", check_positive)
makspuls = get_input_int("Hva er din makspuls?\t", check_positive_or_zero, default=0)


if not makspuls:
    if kjonn == 'm':
        makspuls = int(214 - 0.8*int(alder))
    else:
        makspuls = int(209 - 0.7*int(alder))

prosent60 = (makspuls-hvilepuls)*0.6 + hvilepuls
prosent75 = (makspuls-hvilepuls)*0.75 + hvilepuls
prosent85 = (makspuls-hvilepuls)*0.85 + hvilepuls
prosent90 = (makspuls-hvilepuls)*0.9 + hvilepuls

# Remove decimals
prosent60 = round(prosent60)
prosent75 = round(prosent75)
prosent85 = round(prosent85)
prosent90 = round(prosent90)


print("\n\n")
if kjonn == 'm':
    print("Din kjnn  er:\t\tMann")
else:
    print("Din kjnn  er:\t\tDame")

print("Din alder er:\t\t", alder)
print("Din hvilepuls er:\t", hvilepuls," slag/min")
print("Din makspuls er:\t", makspuls," slag/min")

print("\n\n")
print("Din lavsone er:\t",prosent60,"-",prosent75," slag/min")
print("Din ATsone er:\t",prosent85,"-",prosent90," slag/min")
print("Din VO2max er:\t",prosent90,"-",makspuls," slag/min")


input("\n\nTrykk enter for avslutte")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and thorough explanation. I will have a proper a look at it and makesure I understand it properly :-)

Comment: A couple of questions:

1. When I just press return in the input to obtain 'm' or 'd', the program assumes 'd'. I would have thought it would keep asking until one of the letters is entered?

How would I change it to ask again when 'enter' is pressed without input.

2. I see the ValueError part of the try statement is catching right type but inappropriate values.

Is there an exception type that would do this and blank input, so the error message is printed for blank input as well, or do you have to do it another way.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Correction to question 2. The ValueError produces the error message for blank input (i.e. just pressing 'enter') but not for a negative value for age (alder). If the input is not >=0 the input question is just repeated. I tried combining using TypeError in the except clause but that didn't appear to work. How would I structure the except to print the message for both blank input and values <=0 ?

Comment: Answer 1. I didn't think about it, but the empty string will succeed in the test `in "md"`.  So I changed it to a tuple of values: `in ('m', 'd')`  This fixes that problem.  Answer 2. `ValueError` is the exception when `int()` cannot convert to a number; `int()` will raise `ValueError` if the user just hits the Enter key.  But now I rewrote the program and there is a function for input with another function to validate the input.  Now you get two different messages: one for "input is not even a number" and one for "validation failed".

Comment: Thanks again for the very thorough reply. I will go through it again and check I have understood what is going on :-)

Comment: Just one question regarding the get_input_int function. I may be being a bit thick, but I am not sure I understand the purpose of the default value part of the function. I get that the while true part is to check that the input is not empty, and I understand the try and except part is to check that the input is not empty and a valid integer. However, I don't understand why there is the default value and why do you return the default if it is not empty when there is nothing affecting default value as far as I can see?. I understand that code works, would just really like to know why :-).

Comment: Correction: The while true part seems to be actually stripping the input of white space not checking for an empty input.

Comment: The `while True:` will make it keep trying until the user enters something valid.  Inside, it first strips all white space; if the result is a zero-length string, then the user just hit the Enter key (or entered only white space).  The test for a zero-length string is simply `if not s` in the code; in Python, a zero-length string evaluates to `bool` as `False`, so `not s` will be true if `s` is a zero-length string.  If the user just hits the enter key, `s` is zero-length, and the default value is returned.  Or, if the user enters a valid number, that is returned.  Otherwise we loop again.

Comment: Note that you do not have to use a default value.  The full test is `if not s and default is not None:` and the `default=None` argument in the function means that if you don't provide a value to be used as the default, it will be set to `None`.  So, if the user just hits the Enter key, and you provided a default value, it is returned.

Comment: Thanks very much. Really appreciate the help and the clear and detailed answers :-).